# Binding an Element to a Control Property (string)

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

so, i've found a way to bind a label to a property on current Control

i give it a name:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfGridtest.GridControl" x:Name="GridControlControl1">
```

and than bind to property of this control:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=GridControlControl1, Path=Filter}"></Label>
```

I can see the default value i put in that property.

I am guessing that this isn't working because i am binding to String property which doesn't implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**??

is there some other type i should be using for this property instead of String auto notify my label of changes, or am i going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface should be implemented by the class that contains the property - in this case, by your `WpfGridtest.GridControl`.

Also, if you want to use your properties for UI, consider using a `DependencyProperty` as a storage instead of a private field.

Answer (score 0):

in addition, it is also likely that the default binding mode is one time, so you may have to change it in your `{Binding}`

Comment: also tried adding NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, but also no changes